# Failed to install copula package

Tags: r, package

I  used install.packages("copula") to download the copula package, but RStudio returns the following error message:

```
package ‘copula’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :

> unable to move temporary installation
> ‘C:\Users\sunnytnt1\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\file43b417543b69\copula’
> to ‘C:\Users\sunnytnt1\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\copula’

The downloaded binary packages are in

> C:\Users\sunnytnt1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCYTvH9\downloaded_packages


----------


> library(copula)
Error in library(copula)
```

Comment: R doesn't have permissions to write the package to the normal directory where it stores them (a [permissions issue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx)). You can fix it by updating the permissions, adding the file where it is located (see the third path above) to `.libPaths()`, (not recommended), or specifying `lib.loc` when you call `library` (not really practical).

Comment: On Windows, running R (or RStudio) "as an administrator" often solves these problems. This is an option if you right-click the program when you start it (or you can set "always run as administrator" in the properties of the .exe).